# Error en subconsulta: Esta subconsulta puede devolver como maximo un registro

Tags: sql, select, ms-access

Buen día. Tengo una tabla en una base de datos que contiene registros financieros. Para mostrar los registros en el sistema los filtro por año y por mes.

Las tablas involucradas son las siguientes:

[image: Tablas involucradas]

Lo crucial de la consulta son los campos **mes, categoria** (que es de tipo texto), y **idAnio**, los demás son datos que solo sirven para mostrar al usuario. El sistema debe mostrar los registros cuya categoria haya cambiado respecto al mes anterior.

-

Para darme a entender bien lo ejemplifico: Estos son los registros correspondientes a Enero

[image: Datos de enero]

Luego los registros correspondientes a Febrero:

[image: Datos de Febrero]

Los datos remarcados en amarillo son los que quiero obtener con la consulta. **La idea es mostrar los campos que quiero donde la categoria NO sea igual a la del mes anterior**.

Mi problema es que no encuentro la consulta correcta para mostrar estos registros. Por el momento tengo esta consulta que me arroja un error:

```
SELECT nombre, categoria 
FROM cartera
WHERE mes = 2 
AND idAnio = 54 
AND categoria <>(SELECT categoria FROM cartera WHERE mes = 1 AND idAnio = 54);
```

[image: Error generado]

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Pon un ejemplo basado en datos, quizá serviría a entender mejor. Por otra parte veo un problema serio en el diseño de tus datos, ¿qué sentido tiene una columna `mes` sola  y una columna `idAnio`? ¿Por qué no usas una columna del tipo `DATETIME`?

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta. Mi tabla esta de esa manera debido a la manera de funcionar del sistema.

Comment: Cuando decis que algo tirar un error, aclaralo. En ese caso, seguro que esa consulta te dice que el subquery puede traer mas de un registro, lo cual es logico. Cambia el <> por un not in y se va a arreglar...

Comment: `and categoria NOT IN(select ....)` Prueba algo así...

Comment: Como sugerencia, los detalles de estas preguntas se añaden como texto. Extraer cosas de imágenes para replicar tu problema hace más dispendioso ayudar

Comment: Gracias por sus sugerencias en torno a cómo preguntar, las tomaré en cuenta.

Comment: @gbianchi Tu comentario solucionó mi problema. Puedes agregarlo como respuesta para que lo marque

Comment: El SQLfiddle que confirma la respuesta de bianchi: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84f776/2

Comment: Ok, viendo los datos se entiende mejor. O sea, los datos de enero tienen la categoría `A1` y **algunos datos de febrero tienen también la categoría `A1` y otros tienen la categoría `B`**  y quieres mostrar aquellos datos de febrero que no tienen la misma categoría de enero (mes anterior). ¿Entendí bien? Si es así, todavía hay una laguna, ¿la categoría de `enero` es siempre `A1`? ¿cómo se determina eso? Pregunto porque cuando llegue el mes de `marzo` se presentará la misma situación... ¿cómo determinarás el criterio para marzo?

Comment: Si, entendiste bien. La categoría de enero siempre es A1 por la lógica del negocio. Para cuando se llegue al mes de Marzo la consulta evaluarala categoría del mes de Febrero, esto lo he resuelto a nivel de programación del sistema donde con un ciclo for hago la consulta para cada mes a mostrar

Comment: @A.Cedano fijate en mi respuesta, creo que con la version join soluciona el problema para adelante...

Comment: Excelente @gbianchi. Con tu consulta el problema queda resuelto. De todos modos yo veo un modelo de datos algo temerario, como algo se salga de control en la asignación de la categoría o en campo `mes` que es del tipo `varchar` se va a armar tremendo lío en ese sistema. Pero bueno, ese ya es otro asunto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que tu subconsulta

```
SELECT categoria FROM cartera WHERE mes = 1 AND idAnio = 54
```

Puede llegar a devolver un monton de registros (La db no sabe las reglas de tu tabla ni que datos estan guardados) y entonces, no puede comparar un monton de registros usando <> porque no sabe como.

Para comparar listas, las bases de datos usan la clausula `IN` (y `Not IN`).

Entonces, lo que hay que hacer en este caso, es cambiar el `<>` por un `Not IN`

---

Esta consulta es parametrizable a todos los meses (si siempre quisieras comparar con el mes anterior) de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT nombre, categoria 
FROM cartera c
WHERE mes = 2 
AND idAnio = 54 
AND categoria not in (SELECT categoria FROM cartera WHERE mes = c.mes-1 AND idAnio = 54);
```

Tambien, esta consulta se puede obtener mediante un join

```
SELECT c.nombre, d.categoria 
FROM cartera c
inner join cartera d ON d.mes = c.mes-1 and c.categoria <> d.categoria
WHERE mes = 2 
AND idAnio = 54
```

Esta ultima, basado en que tenes un solo registro por mes para cada nombre. Pero con esta ultima consulta, si sacas el mes, podrias mostrar en que mes cambio cada uno ;)

Answer (score 0):

Según entiendo de tu planteo, el único problema es que en la subconsulta te falta incluir la columna 'nombre', para poder hacer una correspondencia directa y que la subconsulta no devuelva más de un valor.

Para ello, sugiero la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT nombre, categoria 
FROM cartera c1
WHERE mes = 2 
AND idAnio = 54 
AND categoria <>(SELECT categoria FROM cartera c2 WHERE c2.mes = c1.mes - 1 AND c2.idAnio = c1.idAnio AND c2.nombre = c1.nombre);
```

Comment: Esta consulta esta simplemente mal. No leiste ni el error ni los comentarios :(